# Index number for actions based on date

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have such table:

| Date | Index | Actions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.08.2023 |  | Do something |
| 01.08.2023 |  | Do something 2 |
| 01.08.2023 |  | Do something 3 |
| 02.08.2023 |  | Do something else |
| 03.08.2023 |  | Do something |
| 03.08.2023 |  | Do something 2 |

I need to add index number for each action, but I want numbers to start from 1 for each new day, like so:

| Date | Index | Actions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.08.2023 | 1 | Do something |
| 01.08.2023 | 2 | Do something 2 |
| 01.08.2023 | 3 | Do something 3 |
| 02.08.2023 | 1 | Do something else |
| 03.08.2023 | 1 | Do something |
| 03.08.2023 | 2 | Do something 2 |

I had an idea to use "day" formula to extract day number and combine somehow with "if" statements, but it won't work for merged cells like "A2:A4". Problem is that for each month actions quantity can change for each day, as days move. Maybe quick vba macro would work? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)` and fill down? Or trough dynamic array: `=MAP(A2:A7,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIF(A2:x,x)))`

Comment: Sorry, probably I gave not enough information. I cannot enter merged cells as tables in this editor. Here's screenshot of how date cells are merged. Is it possible like that? https://prnt.sc/tPyhTKlcRhmg its not working, as some rows are merged. Or am I forced to unmerge these cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yikes, merged cells, Excel's (or rather it's users) worst nightmare! Since we know only top-left cells have values, we could try to utilize the fact that the rest is empty?

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=SCAN(0,A2:A7,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x+1,1)))
```

Comment: Thank you man, this one is working, and without using any vba. I think I've learned something new, although I need to sit for a while to fully understand SCAN and LAMBDA. Anyway, thank you so muuuch!

Comment: Yea I do not fully understand how this works, but it's way cleaner than my VBA solution!

Comment: Think about iterations where we have a *state* and a *current* value to work with. We can then overwrite the *state*  based on this *value* each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

### Understanding the SCAN Function Using VBA

- The following is a basic inefficient code.
- I wrote it just so one could better understand **JvdV**'s formula above (if familiar with VBA).

```vb
Sub ScanVBA()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim x As Long                             ' '...(0,...,LAMBDA(x,' i.e. x = 0
    Dim y As Variant                          ' '...,A2:A7,LAMBDA(...,y,'

    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A7").Cells  ' '=SCAN(...,A2:A7,LAMBDA('
        y = cell.Value                        ' '...,y,'
        If y = "" Then                        ' 'IF(y=""'
            x = x + 1                         ' ',x+1'
        Else
            x = 1                             ' ',1)'
        End If
        cell.EntireRow.Columns("B").Value = x ' write on each iteration
        Debug.Print y, x ' return iteration result in Immediate window (Ctrl+G)
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Well done, that's a good way to explain.

Answer (score 1):

With the merged cells, I can think of a way to do this in VBA (maybe someone can translate this logic to a formula).

```
Dim dates As Range
Set dates = Worksheets("YourSheet").Range("A2:A100")
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range
' Starting point- set first index
i = 1
dates.Cells(1,1).Value = i
i = i + 1
' Loop through all cells, checking if next is equal or if you have jumped a merged cell
For Each cell in dates
    ' Normal case (next is same as current)
    If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1,0).Value Then
        cell.Offset(1,1).Value = i
    ' The second elseif ensures the jump due to merged cells does not occur
    ElseIf cell.Offset(1,1).Address <> cell.Offset(0,1).Offset(1,0).Address Then
        cell.Offset(0,1).Offset(1,0).Value = i
     ' End condition to stop & Date has changed now
    ElseIf cell.Offset(1,0).Value <> "" Then
        i = 1
        cell.Offset(1,1).Value = i
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next cell
```

The chained .Offset is the key point here, it checks to see if the cell is the same if you go down 1 row and move over 1 column, versus if you go over one column then down 1 row.

Comment: I will give it a try in spare time. Thank you anyway for your time!